# How to analyze multiple .csv files whose names depend on timestamps in a single Python script?

Tags: python, csv, glob, data-analysis

I have some weekly .csv files which are named depending on the start and end date and time of the week, for example:

```
File_2018-01-01_05-30-00_2018-01-08_02-00-00
```

I want to analyze them using a single Python script and my idea was to loop over the `.csv` in the folder and then run the rest of the code.

I know it is possible to concatenate more `.csv` files into a single one, but my computer doesn't support so many and I am interested in the results of the respective periods separately.

Is there any way of using the glob function/library if the names are so different?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `glob.glob("File_*.csv")` to get the list of filenames?

Comment: @MartinEvans I have, it works with `for file in files = glob.glob('C:/Users/...path*.csv'): ...` but I don't know how to apply the script within the loop, get the results, then return to the next file etc.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question and include the code you are working on and explain where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3.x, you can use `glob.glob()` to let you iterate over all suitable filenames as follows:

```
import glob
import csv

for filename in glob.glob("File_*.csv"):
    print("Processing '{}'".format(filename))

    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

        for row in csv_input:
            print(row)

    print()
```

In this example it finds all CSV files starting with `File_`, opens them, displays the filename and then all of the rows from the file. So if for example you had a CSV file called `File_2018-01-01_05-30-00_2018-01-08_02-00-00.csv` containing:

```
col1,col2
a,b
c,d
```

The script would display:

```
Processing 'File_2018-01-01_05-30-00_2018-01-08_02-00-00.csv'
['col1', 'col2']
['a', 'b']
['c', 'd']
```

This would then be repeated for any other matching filenames in the same folder.

If you are using Python 2.x, you would need to modify this line:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f_input:
```